# Escaping glob brackets in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, glob

How to escape ( in glob expression in bash script.
This command runs from shell:

```
rm -rf !(a)
```

It does not run from inside of a bash script:

```
./sc.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./sc.sh: line 2: `rm -rf !(a)'
```

Running on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? !(a) doesn't really make sense - escape or no escape edit: To escape just put a \ e.g. `rm -rf !\(a\)`

Comment: Are you setting `extglob` with `shopt` builtin?

Comment: That does not work. I am trying to remove all directories except for a.

 rm -rf !\(a\) does not work because it tries to remove '!(a)' directory, which does not exist. I know I could use find or other commands but I would like to know how to deal with such issues in the future

Comment: @ozimki: You are missing setting the `shopt -s extglob` option in the script as in the linked question

Comment: shopt -s extglob helped thanks :)